# String parsing using complex patterns

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I have a complex string with an unknown number of letters, numbers, and characters. For instance

```
"a83bal*av31-ab+asf3/af1124-xxx.afe-100/araw31/31*xxx.g41.abt.eta+131as*dfa"
```

The goal is to find the string xxx and extract everything after it until a `+`, `-`, `*` , `/`. Thus I should be able to extract `xxx.afe` and `xxx.g41.abt.eta` Finding the string is simple `string:find("xxx")` the trouble I am having is gathering all of the information following the `"xxx"` until one of the operators. I have tried things like

```
string:match("xxx.(.+[%+%-%*%/])")
```

and several variations of the above, but there is something I am missing.

Answer (score 1):

```
str = "a83bal*av31-ab+asf3/af1124-xxx.afe-100/araw31/31*xxx.g41.abt.eta+131as*dfa"    
for m in str:gmatch("[+%-*/](xxx.-)[+%-*/]") do
    print(m)
end
```

Note that `-` has special meaning even inside char-set (e.g, `[1-9a-f]`), so it must be escaped, or be put in the beginning or end of the char-set, i.e, `[-+*/]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the negated character class to match (`[^-+*/]`):

```
for sWord in str:gmatch "xxx%.([^-+*/]+)" do
    -- do things to sWord
end
```

Note that, looking at your code snippet; you're using variable named `string`. `string` stores the metatable for the general string data types in lua environment. Please avoid using variable names like that.

Comment: `string` does not store the metatable for strings.  It stores `__index` value of that metatable.